# Unable to get Status of Check boxes as a child element of ListView Item

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview

In my code I'm using a structure like in the picture below:

[image]

After checking the `CheckBox`, on `send` `Button` click, I am reading the status of the `CheckBoxes` like the code written below but it is showing me unchecked. 
`CheckboxName.isChecked()` value is `false` but my `CheckBox` is checked:

```
  try {
                int nCount = NotebookList.getCount();
                LinearLayout v;
                View vv;
                CheckBox Available, Display, Demo;
                v = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearNotebookList);
                TextView _id, ID, Name;
                for (int i = 0; i < nCount; i++) {
                    v = (LinearLayout) NotebookList.getAdapter().getView(i, null,
                            null);
                    _id = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_Notebook_ID);

                    Available = (CheckBox) v
                            .findViewById(R.id.chkboxNotebookAvailable);
                    Display = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.chkboxNotebookDisplay);
                    Demo = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.chkboxNotebookDemo);
                    str_id = (String) _id.getText();

                    if (Available.isChecked()) {
                        strAvailable = "YES";
                    } else {
                        strAvailable = "NO";
                    }
                    if (Display.isChecked()) {
                        strDisplay = "YES";
                    } else {
                        strDisplay = "NO";
                    }
                    if (Demo.isChecked()) {
                        strDemo = "YES";
                    } else {
                        strDemo = "NO";
                    }

                    rowID += db.insertAudit(Integer.parseInt(UserId),
                            Integer.parseInt(CityId), Integer.parseInt(OutletId),
                            0, dateTime, "002", Integer.parseInt(str_id),
                            strAvailable, strDisplay, strDemo, null, null, null,
                            null, null, null, null, null, null, null, Instance_Id)
                            + ",";

                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

I've found some that could help

can i do something with the follow if yes please lemme know

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.desktop_list, parent, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the checkboxes working correctly on a listView you will need to use a BaseAdapter class

Comment: can i do something using inflater

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.desktop_list, parent, false);